# How insert into a permanent table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the this stored procedure which calls other procedure (this returns some rows of data).

In the first procedure I need to insert all those rows into a permanent table and return the contents of this table. I have this, but with a temporary table.

How can I insert in a permanent table and then return it?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[paBltBuscarBoletasASA] @id_Asa int  
      -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
DECLARE @Query int
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal (Numero_Pregunta varchar, Numero_Boleta int, Cultivo varchar, Numero_Siembra int, Detalle_Error varchar)
DECLARE miCursor CURSOR FOR

                SELECT 
                    localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
                FROM 
                    Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
                WHERE 
                    boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND
                    localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa
OPEN miCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @Query

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal(Numero_Pregunta, Numero_Boleta, Cultivo, Numero_Siembra, Detalle_Error) exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @Query

    FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @Query
END

CLOSE miCursor
DEALLOCATE miCursor
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Table from stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917865/return-table-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: You insert into a permanent table the **exact same way** as you insert into a temporary table - with an `INSERT INTO` statement. The only difference: a table name with a `#` or `##` at the beginning is a temporary table - otherwise it's a permanent table.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a cursor? There is no need to use a cursor and you should not tie up the database using one. Cursors are often (as in this case) a SQL antipattern and should almost never be used in production code. You should not reuse a one record proc to insert data or update data to handle multiple rcord inserts with a cursor. Adjust the prod to correctly handel multiple record inserts.

Comment: Do you need to replace the permanant table with new data each time the code runs or will you need to return accumulated data?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at the bottom of your stored proc to copy the temp table into a permanent one:

```
-- To insert into a permanent table
INSERT INTO MyPermanentTable (Numero_Pregunta, Numero_Boleta, Cultivo, 
                              Numero_Siembra, Detalle_Error)
SELECT Numero_Pregunta, Numero_Boleta, Cultivo, Numero_Siembra, Detalle_Error
FROM   #tablaTemporal

-- To get the result set that was added back to the caller
SELECT Numero_Pregunta, Numero_Boleta, Cultivo, Numero_Siembra, Detalle_Error
FROM   #tablaTemporal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a result of a stored procedure into a permenant database table then you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyPermenantTable Execute [dbo].[paBltBuscarBoletasASA] parameter1, parameter2
```

Above query worked for me... hope it also works for you.